# Open a Sub-Preference Screen of SettingsActivity on button click

Tags: android, android-activity, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen, android-settings

My **`SettingsActivity`** has sub-preference screens. I want to directly open one of the nested **`PreferenceScreen`** in `SettingsActivity` from another **`Activity`** on button click.

Basically, I want the user to be redirected from an `Activity` to the sub-section of the`SettingsActivity` screen. Is there a way to do it?

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_header_general">
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <ListPreference
    ..
    />
    <PreferenceScreen <!--Show this sub preference screen in Setttings on button click -->

        android:key="@string/pref_key_open_this_screen"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_sample"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_sample" >
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="@string/pref_summary_enabled"
            android:key="@string/pref_key_enabled"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_enabled"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_reminder_enabled"/>
        <ListPreference
        ..
        />
        <ListPreference
        ..
        />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution after some research. Hope it helps somebody else. We can use the code below to simulate click on a sub-preference screen.

- Start an intent to `SettingsActivity` from the activity of your choice.
- Pass an extra to let the `SettingsActivity` know that it needs to open the sub-preference screen
- If`SettingsActivity` receives the intent, run the following code and it will open the sub-preference screen

**Code :**

```
PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen  = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key_root_screen));
PreferenceScreen subPreferenceScreen  = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key_sub_preference_screen));
final ListAdapter listAdapter = preferenceScreen.getRootAdapter();
final int itemsCount = listAdapter.getCount();
int itemNumber;
for (itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < itemsCount; ++itemNumber) {
    if (listAdapter.getItem(itemNumber).equals(subPreferenceScreen)) {
        //simulates click on the sub-preference
        preferenceScreen.onItemClick(null, null, itemNumber, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```